# Finding Time of any Country using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to know each and every country's Date, Time, Month, Year, Day, Hours and Minutes, using only Vanilla JavaScript. Given that I know country's name, its country code(like 'IN' for India) and Timezone Number(eg: 19800 for Delhi), which I got from OpenWeatherAPI. Please help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Why are you not open to something like moment.js ?

Comment: Many countries have multiple timezones (like Russia, United States), so we cannot get a single local time for them.

Comment: You could check out the [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Answer (score 0):

i think the toLocaleDateString might help , it accepts two argument , first one is locales and the second one is options that have some timeZone stuff
read the documentations for more info

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Please try making use of bold words to highlight important info

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time for a given UTC offset by adding this to the current UTC time. We can do this using the Date constructor and the various getUTC..() functions to get the time components.

We have to be careful with using fixed UTC offsets for many locations such as New York. The UTC offset will vary due to Daylight Saving Time, so we have to use the right UTC offset for a given moment in time.

So, when you get a time back from an API with a UTC Offset (or Timezone Number), you should not make the assumption that the UTC offset is fixed for that location.

```js
function getTimeComponentsFromUTCOffset(timeMillis, utcOffsetSeconds) {
    const d = new Date(timeMillis + utcOffsetSeconds * 1000);
    return { 
      year: d.getUTCFullYear(),
      month: d.getUTCMonth() + 1,
      day: d.getUTCDate(),
      hour: d.getUTCHours(),
      minute: d.getUTCMinutes(),
      second: d.getUTCSeconds() 
    };
}

// NB: timeZoneNumber or UTC offset will vary according to local DST rules...
const inputs = [
    { timeZoneNumber: +28800, location: 'Perth' },
    { timeZoneNumber: +19800, location: 'Delhi' },
    { timeZoneNumber: +3600, location: 'London' },
    { timeZoneNumber: -14400, location: 'New York' },
]

console.log('Location'.padEnd(12), 'Year  ', 'Month ', 'Day   ', 'Hour  ', 'Minute', 'Second');
for(let input of inputs) {
    let time = getTimeComponentsFromUTCOffset(Date.now(), input.timeZoneNumber);
    console.log(input.location.padEnd(12), ...Object.values(time).map(s => (s + '').padStart(2, '0').padEnd(6)));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```